# cannot see my external drive

Tags: usb, disk, drive

Hi I can't see my usb external hard drive.

With disk utility it says it's mounted. But I can't find it on the right of nautilus file explorer.

When I try to mounted again, obviously it says it's mounted already. It gave me the error.

```
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdc1 is already mounted on /
```

I google around but didn't find any answer. My disk works fine on Win XP. 
here is what fdisk -l says:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 360.1 GB, 360080695296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 43777 cylinders, total 703282608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x63ce5f06

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1           16065   682891019   341437477+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda2   *   682891020   703277504    10193242+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5           16128   682891019   341437446    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdc: 360.1 GB, 360080695296 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 43777 cylinders, total 703282608 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2357d1b7

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2048   690995199   345496576   83  Linux
/dev/sdc2       690997246   703281151     6141953    5  Extended
/dev/sdc5       690997248   703281151     6141952   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500299395072 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders, total 2930272256 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000822c7

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  2930272255  1465135104    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

here's what more /etc/fstab says:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/sdb1       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=f45e78b8-f7f0-4e98-8e75-7454d7652f58 none            swap    sw                 0       0
```

I also did the ntfsfix. the command was succesful

here is the message.

```
lung@lung-KN226AAR-ABA-m8407c:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Mounting volume... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sdb1 was processed successfully.
```

Comment: what is the size of the hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

> mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdc1 is already mounted on /

As it says it is mounted on root directory, you can find it in nautilus 'Computer' partition or 'System' partition.

If you don't find, try using terminal

```
cd /
ls
```

Comment: I can't find my partition. I even don't know the name it is suppose to have.

Comment: did you boot from external usb hdd?